# Individual Modules Dan't Recognise Variables

Tags: vba, module, call

I have VBA code that opens up a powerpoint template, and I want to create separate modules that will populate the powerpoint template.  The vba that opens up the powerpoint template will be the "MAIN" module and using the CALL command, it will call the other modules that populate the template.  In my case,  when my code gets to the second module, it gives me an object required error.

Here is the code that opens up the powerpoint template:
This one works fine.

```
Public Sub OpenTemplatePowerpoint()
Dim ppApp As powerpoint.Application
Dim ppPres As powerpoint.Presentation
Dim ppslide As powerpoint.Slide  
TemplatePresPath = "powerpointpath"
Set ppApplication = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ppApplication.Visible = True
Set pptemplate = ppApplication.Presentations.Open(Filename:=TemplatePresPath, ReadOnly:=msoFalse) ', WithWindow:=msoFalse)
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("D2").Value = True Then
Call Module1
Else
MsgBox ("AWW")
End If
End Sub
```

Here is sample code of the module that gets called.

```
Set ppslide1 = pptemplate.Slides(1)
ppslide1.Select
With ppslide1.Shapes(15)
.Select
.Table.Cell(3, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheets").Range("L6").Value, "0.00")
End With
End Sub
```

when I debug, this part of the code gets highlighted

```
Set ppslide1 = pptemplate.Slides(1)
```

is it because I need to pptemplate needs to be declared again? If so, how do I assign pptemplate to my current powerpoint that is already open?

Comment: Two options that come to mind are 1) keep all this in one sub or 2) pass your variables from sub to sub as parameters.

Comment: You can't "call" a module, you "call" a *procedure* that's inside a module - and the `Call` keyword is optional/redundant.

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module. Go Tools > Options > General > check the "Require variable declaration" checkbox: your code will compile again when no undeclared variables are left.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to *parameterize* the called procedure, and pass the `Presentation` as a parameter - you'll want to pass a *copy* of the object pointer; that's done with the `ByVal` modifier:

```
Public Sub TheOtherProcedure(ByVal pptemplate As Presentation)
    Dim ppslide As Slide
    Set ppslide = pptemplate.Slides(1)
    With ppslide.Shapes(15)
        .Table.Cell(3, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheets").Range("L6").Value, "0.00")
    End With
End Sub
```

If you don't specify `ByVal`, you get the implicit default which is `ByRef`, where you're passing a *reference* to the object pointer. This has bug-prone implications you will want to avoid.

```
Public Sub OpenTemplatePowerpoint()
    Dim ppApp As powerpoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As powerpoint.Presentation
    Dim ppslide As powerpoint.Slide  
    TemplatePresPath = "powerpointpath"
    Set ppApplication = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppApplication.Visible = True
    Set pptemplate = ppApplication.Presentations.Open(Filename:=TemplatePresPath, ReadOnly:=msoFalse) ', WithWindow:=msoFalse)
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("D2").Value = True Then
        'invoke TheOtherProcedure like this:
        Module1.TheOtherProcedure pptemplate
        'or like this:
        TheOtherProcedure pptemplate
        'or like this:
        Call Module1.TheOtherProcedure(pptemplate)
        'or like this:
        Call TheOtherProcedure(pptemplate)
    Else
        MsgBox "AWW"
    End If
End Sub
```

You're getting an *object required* error because `Option Explicit` isn't specified, which allows VBA to happily compile even though you're using undeclared variables - which means any typo you make will not be caught by the compiler... and that an undeclared `pptemplate` therefore just an empty `Variant`; yet member calls (like `pptemplate.Slides`) can only ever be made against an object - and since `Empty` isn't an object, that's why the runtime throws "object required". By specifying `Option Explicit`, you move that error to *compile-time*, and now the compiler can't resolve `pptemplate` since it's undeclared, and refuses to run code that it can't compile. ..which is much more robust. Always use `Option Explicit`.